# Submit data with attachment Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have to submit data with attachment using java scripts and PHP, my problem is that I cant pass data and attachment to php page. here is my codes;

In my HTML i did not use

```
    function kk_sendmail() 
{
    var kk_vtype= $("#vtype").val();
    var kk_departm= $("#departm").val();
    var kk_recepient= $("#recepient").val();
    var kk_user= $("#euser").val();
    var kk_smssubject= $("#smssubject").val();
    var kk_compose_textarea= $("#compose-textarea").val();
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('attach', $('#attachments').prop('files')[0]);
    form_data.append('vtype',kk_vtype);
    form_data.append('departm',kk_departm);
    form_data.append('recepient',kk_recepient);
    form_data.append('euser',kk_user);
    form_data.append('smssubject',kk_smssubject);
    form_data.append('compose-textarea',kk_compose_textarea);
        
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        dataType: 'text',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
            formSuccess();
            } else {
            console.log('Failed message');
            }
        }
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to define the dataType and also you can use

```
enctype: "multipart/form-data",

$('#attachements')[0].files[0] // for file
```

It will help

Comment: thank you for your help. Though it did not solve.

Comment: how are you passing the file ? try 
$('#attachments')[0].files[0]) and
enctype: "multipart/form-data",

Comment: Well, Finally I solved the problem. Thank you @Shashank Shekhar